# jQuery datepicker not closing

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

My jQuery datepicker only closes when picking a date, but I want it to close when the user clicks away from or on the close button. However, even with the *showButtonPanel* option set to true, the close button does not appear but the 'Today' button does.

I think it may have something to with having a custom onSelect action instead of the default but can't figure out how to close it myself. Tried using $.datepicker('hide') and ('destroy') but no difference.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({firstDay: 1, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', showAnim: 'fade'});
});    
$(document).delegate('.editEndDate', 'click', function() {              
$('.formattedEndDate').datepicker({
    defaultDate: $('.formattedEndDate').attr('id'),
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
    var date = dateText;
    var data = 'project=' + projectId + '&date=' + date + '&dateToChange=end';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'helpers/change-project-date.php',
            data: data + '&ajax=1',
            success: function(response){
                getNotification(response);
                $('.formattedEndDate').fadeOut(function() {
                    $(this).load(location.href+ ' .formattedEndDate', function() {
                        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
                    });
                });     
            },
            error: function(response){
                getNotification(response);
            },
            complete: function(response){
                $('.formattedEndDate').datepicker('hide');
            }
        });
    }
});
return false;
});
```

It may be something simple but I just can't see it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use this script    $(document).click(function (e) {
        var ele = $(e.target);
        if (!ele.hasClass("hasDatepicker") && !ele.hasClass("ui-datepicker") && !ele.hasClass("ui-icon") && !$(ele).parent().parents(".ui-datepicker").length)
            $(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("hide");
    });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have found a solution to my own problem...

```
$('.ui-datepicker').live('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.ui-datepicker').fadeOut(function() {
        $('.formattedStartDate').attr('class', 'formattedStartDate');
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

This works for me, hopefully it'll work for others too.

Answer (score 0):

Everything blew up when I tried to use live.  So I had to use on.  I also added in input focus hide.  So if you happen to focus on a different field the calendar isn't just hanging around.  I also just did hide, but you should be able to switch it for fade if that is what you are wanting.

```
    $('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').on('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).hide();
    })
    $('input').on('focus', function () {
        $('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').hide();
    });
```